# Applying user settings on a Windows Server 2008r2 server slow from external computers

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, domain-controller, remote-desktop-services

I have 2 almost indentical environments consisting of a Windows 2008r2 server host running hyper-v and on each host I have 2 Windows Server 2008r2 guests. One of them acts as Domain Controller and 1 as Terminal Server to which users connect.

Users connect to this Terminal Server from various windows operating systems: Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7, 32bit and 64bit systems mixed. Users can connect from computers on the local network, but also from their homecomputers.

The hosts have fixed IP address (192.168.254.250) and the router forwards the incomming requests to port 3389 are forwarded to 192.168.254.250.

On 1 location everything runs fine and smooth, on the other premise the innitial connection to the terminal server goes as quickly as the other, but once you see "Applying User Settings" it takes ages to log in.

The point is: when connecting to the server within the local network, everything goes fast and smoothly, when connecting to the server from outside the local network for example from home, it takes ages... It works, but takes ages to get your RDP-environment.

User log in from a non-domain computer, but with a domain user login

Somewhere on the net I found that sluggish performance using RDP and Hyper-V has to do with Large Send Offload Version 2 (IPv4) I disabled these on the host and and VM

I have disabled this, but nothing has change so far.

I think it can't be related to this Offloading, as on the internal network everything goes smoothly.

Could someone put me in the right direction?

Comment: Roaming profiles? (And/or offline files?)

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you have a Hyper-V host at each location? How are these locations connected to each other? Does each Hyper-V host run a DC and a TS VM? Do you have Active Directory Sites and Services setup correctly (assuming two locations on different networks)? Being stuck at "Applying Computer Settings" makes me think that it's getting stuck because it's "pulling" Group Policy from the remote site instead of the local site.

Comment: @Dinobe Try enabling [verbose logon](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325376) - it might tell you where exactly it hangs.

Comment: @joeqwerty I have a hyper-v host at each location, each hyper-v host has 2 VM's running: "Terminal Server" on which the users remotely connect and a Domain controller. The locations are not connected to each other, but have a similar set up. Some users work on both locations and connect on both systems.

Comment: Apparently I have able to solve the problem. The DNS service on the domain controller had a non-verifiable DNS server configured in the forward lookup zone. After adding the correct DNS Server (from our service provider) RDP'ing is flying again.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You have one of your ISP's DNS servers in your AD forward lookup zone? If so, why?

Comment: A while ago we changed to another ISP. It slipped our attention to change the DNS server in the forward lookup zone. Apparently this made connecting via RDP extremely slow. I have no idea why or how this exactly worked...